# Installing pyinstaller using Anaconda (on Windows)

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, pyinstaller

I'm trying to install "pyinstaller" to my base environment using Anaconda.
I am using a Windows 10 setup.
I have not installed pyinstaller on my environment/setup before.

I'm wondering why the command

```
conda install -c conda-forge pyinstaller
```

gives me this output:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: D:\Anaconda

  added / updated specs:
    - pyinstaller


The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    altgraph-0.17              |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          21 KB  conda-forge
    ca-certificates-2020.11.8  |       h5b45459_0         183 KB  conda-forge
    certifi-2020.11.8          |   py38haa244fe_0         150 KB  conda-forge
    conda-4.9.2                |   py38haa244fe_0         3.1 MB  conda-forge
    macholib-1.14              |     pyh9f0ad1d_1          34 KB  conda-forge
    openssl-1.1.1h             |       he774522_0         5.8 MB  conda-forge
    pefile-2019.4.18           |             py_0          52 KB  conda-forge
    pyinstaller-4.1            |   py38hd0d6af5_1         2.4 MB  conda-forge
    pyinstaller-hooks-contrib-2020.10|     pyhd8ed1ab_0          65 KB  conda-forge
    python_abi-3.8             |           1_cp38           4 KB  conda-forge
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:        11.7 MB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  altgraph           conda-forge/noarch::altgraph-0.17-pyhd8ed1ab_0
  macholib           conda-forge/noarch::macholib-1.14-pyh9f0ad1d_1
  pefile             conda-forge/noarch::pefile-2019.4.18-py_0
  pyinstaller        conda-forge/win-64::pyinstaller-4.1-py38hd0d6af5_1
  pyinstaller-hooks~ conda-forge/noarch::pyinstaller-hooks-contrib-2020.10-pyhd8ed1ab_0
  python_abi         conda-forge/win-64::python_abi-3.8-1_cp38

The following packages will be UPDATED:

  ca-certificates    pkgs/main::ca-certificates-2020.10.14~ --> conda-forge::ca-certificates-2020.11.8-h5b45459_0

The following packages will be SUPERSEDED by a higher-priority channel:

  certifi            pkgs/main::certifi-2020.11.8-py38haa9~ --> conda-forge::certifi-2020.11.8-py38haa244fe_0
  conda               pkgs/main::conda-4.9.2-py38haa95532_0 --> conda-forge::conda-4.9.2-py38haa244fe_0
  openssl                                         pkgs/main --> conda-forge
```

but the command

```
conda install pyinstaller
```

gives me that output:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: D:\Anaconda

  added / updated specs:
    - pyinstaller


The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    altgraph-0.17              |             py_0          22 KB
    macholib-1.14              |             py_1          36 KB
    pefile-2019.4.18           |             py_0          57 KB
    pycryptodome-3.9.9         |   py38h2bbff1b_0         9.7 MB
    pyinstaller-3.6            |   py38h62dcd97_5         1.7 MB
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:        11.5 MB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  altgraph           pkgs/main/noarch::altgraph-0.17-py_0
  macholib           pkgs/main/noarch::macholib-1.14-py_1
  pefile             pkgs/main/noarch::pefile-2019.4.18-py_0
  pycryptodome       pkgs/main/win-64::pycryptodome-3.9.9-py38h2bbff1b_0
  pyinstaller        pkgs/main/win-64::pyinstaller-3.6-py38h62dcd97_5
```

I'd like to know what the differences between these two commands are
and which I should run for a reliable installation of pyinstaller to my Anaconda environment.

I bet for the first one :D

Thank you very much!